# Dropdownlist being generated differently from same template

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a class ProfileViewModel that has a list of DJTypeModel which uses the following template

```
@using DigitalDjPool.Website.Domain.Profiles
@model DigitalDJPool.Website.UI.Models.ProfileWizard.UserDJTypeModel

<div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="input-field col m4 s12"><h5>What type of DJ are you?</h5>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserMemberTypeId)
    <div class="input-field col m4 s12">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMemberType, ((IEnumerable<MemberType>)Model.MemberTypesList)
            .Select(t => new SelectListItem { Value = t.Id.ToString(), Text = t.Name, Selected = t.Id.ToString().CompareTo(Model.SelectedMemberType) == 0 }), new { @class = "editprofile-info-ddl" })
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col m4 s12">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MemberTypeInfo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.MemberTypeInfo)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="input-field col m4 s12"><h5> What is your typical audience size? </h5></div>
<div class="input-field col m4 s12">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AudienceSize, new List<string> {"1-50", "50-499", "500+"}.Select(t => new SelectListItem {Value = t, Text = t, Selected = t == Model.AudienceSize}))
</div>
    </div>
```

for some weird reason when I initially create the page the dropdown lists come out right [image: Way it should be] yet when I use a ajax call to add another UserDjTypeModel to the page the html script I receive back screws up the Dropdown lists. I receive the same code as what is in the chrome view source page but when I inspect element there is another tag on the one created during page load. I have checked and there is no JSScript running on this. The folloing is code seen in both the source page and in the html returned via AJAX

```html
<div class="row no-margin UserDjTypeModelObj">
    <div class="input-field col m4 s12"><h5>What type of DJ are you?</h5>
    </div>
    <input id="UserDJTypeModel_0__UserMemberTypeId" name="UserDJTypeModel[0].UserMemberTypeId" type="hidden" value="2ad4c348-0120-4eeb-b031-a5b0008d0d43" />
    <div class="input-field col m4 s12">
        <select class="editprofile-info-ddl" id="UserDJTypeModel_0__SelectedMemberType" name="UserDJTypeModel[0].SelectedMemberType"><option value="f4579c21-8509-49df-9329-00fc33bd3344">College Radio</option>
<option selected="selected" value="8f670bf6-1a95-4c30-abac-2acac6fd3e05">FM Radio</option>
<option value="b9b14aca-81d2-49a1-9393-3c2e6552ff71">Mobile DJ</option>
<option value="d2744e05-8f19-4c80-915c-60f7582792d0">Tour DJ</option>
<option value="c7aa4e2a-0b77-4ce1-af51-7683e50c3b8f">Internet Radio</option>
<option value="8e4e882a-c650-4841-beb7-c18105b929ad">Satellite Radio</option>
<option value="561dcbec-e6d6-4f28-ae64-c50be123e64e">Bedroom DJ</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col m4 s12">
        <input id="UserDJTypeModel_0__MemberTypeInfo" name="UserDJTypeModel[0].MemberTypeInfo" type="text" value="98.7" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserDJTypeModel[0].MemberTypeInfo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="input-field col m4 s12"><h5> What is your typical audience size? </h5></div>
<div class="input-field col m4 s12">
    <select id="UserDJTypeModel_0__AudienceSize" name="UserDJTypeModel[0].AudienceSize"><option value="1-50">1-50</option>
<option value="50-499">50-499</option>
<option selected="selected" value="500+">500+</option>
</select>
</div>
```

this is how the returned object comes out 
[image] as you can see both drop down lists fail to display though the html code is there

Comment: To clarify, are you returning a model from your ajax call or html code?

Comment: Im returning a partial view (as html) of the model to ajax which inserts the html into the dom

Comment: Is the partial view already in the page before the ajax call, or is it loaded after? Edit: I mean do you load it twice?

Comment: itsa partial view for a list of these models so I replace the existing code when the ajax call is made

Comment: Can I see the onSuccess portion of the ajax code?

Comment: success: function(data) {
                loading = false;
                $('#userDjQ').html(data);
            }

Comment: the html code is being inserted properly into the page its just not being displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104199/discussion-between-jared-beach-and-alex-krupka).

Answer (score 1):

*sigh* My company is using Materialize apparently Materialize requires a Js update call after inserting new select lists into the DOM. See http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select the initialize section

Comment: Dang, hopefully this will help someone.